# Android - VerifyError

Tags: android, verifyerror

this is an error I am getting in Android Developer Console from hundreds of my users.

I've spend entire day trying to fix the issue in code and it took 9 releases and I am still getting these error reports. My application has about 5 thousand downloads a day and on about 10% of the devices it's crashing. Rating of my application went down from 4.7 to 3.0 in just one day because of this.

I literally can't figure this out.

I am at the point of letting someone actually remote connect to my machine and pay to look at it.

Anyhow, long story short. I've done an update in code last night and I've uninstalled google ads from my app. Added little bit of code and released app to android market. This morning I had 200 error reports. App is crashing on many devices.

I went to error reports and this is what most people are getting:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: a.xml.a$Searching
at a.xml.a.startTalkingActivity(a.java:849)
at a.xml.a.onActivityResult(a.java:1053)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've put ads back in, but error keep coming. I've removed code I've added, error still there and getting more angry reviews complaining of crashing on a button press.

I am going crazy here, I'd appreciate any help with this. I can't figure out what this error means.

Comment: Basically, class `a.xml.a$Searching` could not be "verified".  Something about the class is wrong, though you don't get much of a clue as what it might be.  (Almost as frustrating as "NoClassDefFoundError".)  Most likely there is a mismatch between your class and another class in a jar file on the device, in terms of types on a method call, etc.  This happens when the jar version changes in a non-compatible fashion (which unfortunately is not uncommon).  You may get some clue if you categorize the failures by phone brand, type, and Android version -- may be a brand or version that fails.

Comment: Are you using ProGuard obfuscate your source? try build application without obfuscate your code.

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that? And do I really want to release code of my app unobfuscated?

Comment: I didn't ask you publish it, if you are using ProGuard/obfuscating, try build without obfuscating and test it, to see if it is actually caused by obfuscating.

Comment: Ok sorry, maybe I didn't explain, that I can't reproduce this on my own Android devices, crashing comes from a small group of my users. About 10% of them, and I have a feeling it's 2.2 Android and below, but I can't be sure, because Google won't give me those stats.

Comment: It seems that only Android 2.2.x are having the problems, any way to find out why it would be only happening on those devices?

Comment: To yorkw: in my case, the VerifyError appear when obfuscating code and running it in 1.6 (real machine and emulator). it disappear whitout obfuscating.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to have a `Searching` inner class of the `a.xml.a` class. That `Searching` inner class is referring to something that does not exist on the users' devices, even though it existed in your build target.

You might temporarily drop your build target to be the same as your `minSdkVersion` (if it isn't there already) and see if anything turns up in this class.

Beyond that, try to find common characteristics of the devices on which the app is failing (e.g., OS version).

Comment: It is so extremely frustrating,... I've spent entire day and still have no clue what it could be, nor exactly how to approach this issue.

Comment: @jjj: You could start by following the instructions in the second paragraph of my answer. Or, try running your application in older emulators to see if you can reproduce the problem (should occur the first time you try referring to `a.xml.a`). Or, paste the source code to `Searching` into your answer so others can review it.

Comment: Searching source code has about 2000 lines. But could this have something to do with my own machine? I can't see anything I've done in code. Java update? Some Eclipse update or change?

Comment: @jjj: "But could this have something to do with my own machine?" -- no. "I can't see anything I've done in code." -- then use your version control system to roll back to a known good version of the code.

Comment: I found that issue is somehow related to prior vs. 2.3 of Android. I've released my app with this limit and I get no more errors. Not a solution, but hey...

Comment: I've fixed the issue, had to cut the class to smaller chunks, it was too long.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to give my solution to this problem, since I haven't really found this anywhere else.

I was able to solve the issue by double-checking the **build path** of the project. I always get the error when I forget to **export external libraries**. Hope this helps someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue, had to cut the class to smaller chunks, it was too long.

Comment: Then you should mark this post as the right answer (green checkmark). Maybe you could give some details on your solution also.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after doing the Android ADT and Java updates. Try these steps:

1. Remove links to your external libraries in your Android project.
2. Move all your external libraries (including Google Ad libraries) to \libs folder inside your Android project.
3. Re-link your libraries, that now exist in the Project\libs directory.