# Android record in FLAC file

Tags: java, android, flac

How can I make a record with a microphone in FLAC file?
I have tried this:

```
import javaFlacEncoder.FLAC_FileEncoder;

FLAC_FileEncoder flacEncoder = new FLAC_FileEncoder();
File outputFile = new File(dir + "/flac1.flac");
flacEncoder.encode(file, outputFile);
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5891): java.lang.VerifyError: javaFlacEncoder/FLAC_FileEncoder
```

Whether it is possible to record sound in format Wav using Java 1.6 and android 4.0.3?

Comment: This looks oddly familiar and I could have sworn that the current build tools in later ADT versions sorted out that issue. But try recompiling your FLAC encoder classes with Java 1.6 compliance level. If you develop in Eclipse or similar and the FLAC encoder sources are hosted in a Java library project, make sure that you change the project settings accordingly (Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler Compliance Level > 1.6)

Comment: Developed in Eclipse, java 1.6. Android 4.0.3.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115775/android-verifyerror -- That kind of error can occur (along with `NoClassDefFoundError`) when a class references something from the runtime environment that does not exist. That is typically the case when you try to use components and methods that have been introduced with Java 1.7 and later.

Comment: Do you also compile that Java library using JRE 6? Check your project settings and see if that Java Compiler page shows a warning symbol.

Comment: Whether it is possible to record sound in format Wav using Java 1.6 and android 4.0.3?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: are you trying to run something on the Android platform that uses components which are not available on the Android platform, such as the majority of `javax` components. If your FLAC encoder uses anything from the `javax.sound.sampled` package for example, then it won't run on Android, because these components do not exist there. Instead you must use Android-specific components such as http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html

Answer (score 0):

From what earlier comments here were alluding to:

From this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioCodec.html) Android appears only support AMR, PCM and GSM codecs. If you need .flac (often google's services favorite) I suggest using the lossless PCM (supports .wav) formats and using FFMPEG, SOX or some other audio converter service to then make them .flac.

(all codecs implemented in Android 3.1x (level 12) so this should apply to your version)